# Difference between kappa statistics

Tags: agreement-statistics, psychometrics, cohens-kappa, validity

I am currently developing an instrument and have some questions on the use of kappa statistics for interrater agreement used for content validity. I have gone through previous literature and I still can't seem to find the exact differences between kappa statistics, Cohen's kappa and fleiss kappa. What I'm particularly curious about to know is the difference between kappa statistic and fleiss kappa. I have seen some papers refer to kappa statistic as Cohen's kappa.

But my understanding is that Cohen's kappa is used for 2 raters and the papers having multiple raters use kappa statistic. I am very confused about this. Is Fleiss kappa and kappa statistic the same? If so, why not refer to fleiss kappa?